# Laravel 4: RouteNotFoundException with Route::resources

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have the following error when try to access to localhost:8000/users after a login success:

```
    RouteNotFoundException: Unable to generate a URL for the named route "users" as 
    such route does not exist.
```

My controller is:

```
<?php

class UserController extends BaseController {

    //public $restful = TRUE;

    public function index()
    {
        return View::make('users.index')
            ->with('title', "Title Example")
            ->with('users', User::all());
    }


    public function create()
    {
        return View::make('users.new')
            ->with('title', "New User");
    }

    ...
```

My routes.php:

```
Route::resource('users', 'UserController');

Route::get('login', array( 'as' =>'login','uses' => 'UserController@login'));

Route::post('login', function(){

    $credentials = array('email' => Input::get('email'), 'password' => Input::get('password'));

    if (Auth::attempt($credentials))
    {
         return Redirect::route('users.index');
    }
    else
    {
        return Redirect::back()->withInput()->with('login_errors',true);;
    }   

});

Route::get('logout', function(){

        Auth::logout();

        return Redirect::route('login');
});
```

Console php artisan routes

```
GET /                                                   Closure                         
GET /users                       users.index            UserController@index            
GET /users/create                users.create           UserController@create           
POST /users                      users.store            UserController@store            
GET /users/{users}               users.show             UserController@show             
GET /users/{users}/edit          users.edit             UserController@edit             
PUT /users/{users}               users.update           UserController@update           
PATCH /users/{users}                                    UserController@update           
DELETE /users/{users}            users.destroy          UserController@destroy          
GET /login                       login                  UserController@login            
POST /login                                             Closure                         
GET /logout                                             Closure
```

Exception:

```
in /Users/sangar1982/Sites/tlaravel4/vendor/symfony/routing/Symfony/Component/Routing/Generator/UrlGenerator.php line 134
at UrlGenerator->generate('users', array(), true) in /Users/sangar1982/Sites/tlaravel4/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/UrlGenerator.php line 181
at UrlGenerator->route('users') in /Users/sangar1982/Sites/tlaravel4/bootstrap/compiled.php line 4299
at Facade::__callStatic('route', array('users')) in /Users/sangar1982/Sites/tlaravel4/app/storage/views/5fc6ba4595a2ad28f9c15b73141f869f line 30
at URL::route('users') in /Users/sangar1982/Sites/tlaravel4/app/storage/views/5fc6ba4595a2ad28f9c15b73141f869f line 30
at include('/Users/sangar1982/Sites/tlaravel4/app/storage/views/5fc6ba4595a2ad28f9c15b73141f869f') in /Users/sangar1982/Sites/tlaravel4/bootstrap/compiled.php line 15928
at PhpEngine->evaluatePath('/Users/sangar1982/Sites/tlaravel4/bootstrap/../app/storage/views/5fc6ba4595a2ad28f9c15b73141f869f', array('__env' => object(Environment), 'app' => object(Application), 'errors' => object(MessageBag), 'title' => 'Title Example', 'users' => object(Collection))) in /Users/sangar1982/Sites/tlaravel4/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Engines/CompilerEngine.php line 45
at CompilerEngine->get('/Users/sangar1982/Sites/tlaravel4/app/config/../views/layouts/backend.blade.php', array('__env' => object(Environment), 'app' => object(Application), 'errors' => object(MessageBag), 'title' => 'Title Example', 'users' => object(Collection))) in /Users/sangar1982/Sites/tlaravel4/bootstrap/compiled.php line 15692
at View->getContents() in /Users/sangar1982/Sites/tlaravel4/bootstrap/compiled.php line 15675
at View->render() in /Users/sangar1982/Sites/tlaravel4/app/storage/views/178250f445fac7ac6adce8b5af153a21 line 8
at include('/Users/sangar1982/Sites/tlaravel4/app/storage/views/178250f445fac7ac6adce8b5af153a21') in /Users/sangar1982/Sites/tlaravel4/bootstrap/compiled.php line 15928
at PhpEngine->evaluatePath('/Users/sangar1982/Sites/tlaravel4/bootstrap/../app/storage/views/178250f445fac7ac6adce8b5af153a21', array('__env' => object(Environment), 'app' => object(Application), 'errors' => object(MessageBag), 'title' => 'Title Example', 'users' => object(Collection))) in /Users/sangar1982/Sites/tlaravel4/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Engines/CompilerEngine.php line 45
at CompilerEngine->get('/Users/sangar1982/Sites/tlaravel4/app/config/../views/users/index.blade.php', array('__env' => object(Environment), 'app' => object(Application), 'errors' => object(MessageBag), 'title' => 'Title Example', 'users' => object(Collection))) in /Users/sangar1982/Sites/tlaravel4/bootstrap/compiled.php line 15692
at View->getContents() in /Users/sangar1982/Sites/tlaravel4/bootstrap/compiled.php line 15675
at View->render() in /Users/sangar1982/Sites/tlaravel4/bootstrap/compiled.php line 16983
at Response->setContent(object(View)) in /Users/sangar1982/Sites/tlaravel4/bootstrap/compiled.php line 16015
at Response->__construct(object(View)) in /Users/sangar1982/Sites/tlaravel4/bootstrap/compiled.php line 7407
at Router->prepare(object(View), object(Request)) in /Users/sangar1982/Sites/tlaravel4/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Controllers/Controller.php line 156
at Controller->processResponse(object(Router), 'index', object(View)) in /Users/sangar1982/Sites/tlaravel4/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Controllers/Controller.php line 126
at Controller->callAction(object(Application), object(Router), 'index', array()) in /Users/sangar1982/Sites/tlaravel4/bootstrap/compiled.php line 7094
at Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}()
at call_user_func_array(object(Closure), array()) in /Users/sangar1982/Sites/tlaravel4/bootstrap/compiled.php line 13427
at Route->callCallable() in /Users/sangar1982/Sites/tlaravel4/bootstrap/compiled.php line 13406
at Route->run(object(Request)) in /Users/sangar1982/Sites/tlaravel4/bootstrap/compiled.php line 7114
at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in /Users/sangar1982/Sites/tlaravel4/bootstrap/compiled.php line 958
at Application->dispatch(object(Request)) in /Users/sangar1982/Sites/tlaravel4/bootstrap/compiled.php line 946
at Application->run() in /Users/sangar1982/Sites/tlaravel4/public/index.php line 49
at require_once('/Users/sangar1982/Sites/tlaravel4/public/index.php') in /Users/sangar1982/Sites/tlaravel4/server.php line 19
```

I´m not able to find what is wrong. It seems all ok.

Can someone help me, please? Thanks!

Updated with exception log

Comment: Perhaps show more of the exception. It should give a fairly good indication of where the call is originating from.

Comment: Thanks @JasonLewis. I updated the question with the exception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the exception it appears as though one of your views is calling `URL::route('user')`. Double check all your views to ensure that you're calling the correct routes.

Comment: Thanks @JasonLewis, I forgot to check in the layout file...it was there

Comment: No worries. Always pays to check your stack traces. They can seem "urgh" at first but 99% of the time they'll tell you something crucial. :)